# Can you add col and row totals to a R Shiny datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am creating a app in R shiny and using a datatable which updates with my input selection. I want to add row and column totals to this (so it looks like a pivot table).

I have tried adding footers but it just prints some numbers and doesn't look very neat.

Is it possible to add them so they automatically update with the input selected?

Comment: You can use `addmargins` (depends on the structure of the data though) or `rowSums/colSums` and then do `cbind/rbind`

Comment: You'll get help faster if you include some basic code of a working app.